# Why don't we remember the Churban in Shabbat and Rosh Chodesh musaf?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chagim-holidays, churban-destruction

The requirement to remember the churban is incumbent upon Jews every day ([top](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_7_Issue_8.pdf) of page 2) and is especially important at times of [joy](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/torah/98400/halachically-speaking-zecher-lchurban-part-2.html). Aside from the [practices](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zecher_LeChurban) of leaving a wall unfinished/unpainted, or leaving food aside, or not listening to music, there are liturgical changes which reflect an awareness.

Though it might not be the primary reason, I would think that including a mention of the exile in Megillat Esther (and all the moreso, using the tune of Eicha when reading it) would be a reminder during a joyful holiday. Breaking a plate and/or glass as a reminder during the simcha of a wedding is also a reminder. Saying "al naharot bavel" reminds us on weekdays. And on Yom Tov and rosh chodesh shechal b'shabbat we say a line in musaf which explicitly recalls that our sins brought forth the destruction of the temple which prevents our offering korbanot, so even on those joyous days, we recall the churban.

But on Shabbat, and on a rosh chodesh which falls on a weekday, that sentiment is missing from Musaf. In both cases, we do use the future tense and indicate a hope that we will offer korbanot in the future, but the text lacks the specific statement which would recall the churban.

I understand that one could say that the other food/furnishing practices still exist on those days, but those remembrances would also be active on Yom Tov, so why is there a need to recall the churban explicitly in the davening on those days?

Bottom line, why does the text for Musaf on Shabbat and on R"C (two days of simcha) not have the zecher of the churban while the zecher is there on Yom Tov and Shabbat-R"C?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35843/mentioning-our-sins-on-shabbos-rosh-chodesh

Comment: @Yishai yes, but I was troubled by the question because it ignores "zman kaparah" which precedes the "mizbe'ach chadash" on a weekday rosh chodesh.

Comment: I don't know who voted to close, as I don't think it is actually a duplicate. Not that I really get the premise this question, because I think the idea of the Beis Hamikdash and how it is missing is well represented in both Musafs. I suppose questioning textual variation is always useful, though, so perhaps some meaningful insight will be found.

Comment: @Yishai The answer to that question also doesn't deal with the lack of mention on Shabbat -- if it is enough to raise a rosh chodesh to a yom tov status, why on a regular shabbat don't we mention the churban? Also, that question is focusing on the sins and I am curious about the liturgical insertion of a reference to the churban.

Comment: "but those remembrances would also be active on Yom Tov" Really? You'd leave out part of the meal on Yom Tov? Isn't that Avelut beFarhesia?

Answer (score -2):

You're not meant to be sad on joyous occasions. Mourners don't mourn on Shabbos, fasts are pushed off if they fall on Shabbos (except yom Kippur)

Comment: This answer would be much stronger if it would address the fact that Chagim, as mentioned in the question, include mention of the Churban and are joyous occasions, and, of course, if it would cite sources for its assertions.